# Why did my video performance decresase recently?

Tags: video, dell, performance, intel, dualhead

I've been running ubuntu 12.04 for the last month without any problem, just yesterday a problem with the video performance came up.

I'm using compiz (always used it) but now, everything is slower and heavy.. like playing a game at 15 FPS.

I didn't install any updates recently.. so I'm using same old drivers as two days ago when everything was working great.

> Dell Studio 1558 - Intel HD - 4GB RAM - 250 GB HD - Ubuntu as main and unique OS with a secondary screen connected to the laptop to extend the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause for this problem, seems that Desktop sharing once enabled but IDLE was forcing -somehow- to decrease the video performance, not sure why, as I said it was just standing by for an incoming connection.

Found the process with top, and right after killing it, the video came back to normal.